# Remote query execute with postgres_fdw, using an indexes

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, postgres-fdw

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33878255/3804906) `postgres_fdw` has no access to indexes.

A workaround is to create an view on remote server and then create foreign table wrapper to this view on local one.

But what if I want to pass a parameter to my view? Normally I would create a `function(myparam)` that `RETURNS TABLE()`. But how call it via `postgres_fdw`?

Any ideas to solve this situation (prefer to not use `dblink` if it is not needed)?

**EXAMPLE**

I have query like this to execute on my remote database:

```
select count(f.id_foo)
from foo f 
where f.date < _my_date
```

As you can see there is an param `_my_date` inside.

So I have created foreign table `my_remote_server_public.my_remote_server_public_foo` and run it from local database like:

```
select count(f.id_foo)
from my_remote_server_public.my_remote_server_public_foo f 
where f.date < _my_date
```

But when I do this - it lasts 2-3 minutes becouse `postgres_fdw` has no access to `foo` indexes.

I thought about creating a function `get_foo_by_date(_my_date date)` on a remote database and call it via `postgres_fdw` from the local one but dont know is it even possible...

**UPDATE**

Let's assume I will handle a normal view as a foreign table with constant date inside.

This view will return me an list of IDs from remote table.

I want to delete listed rows from remote table and archive these into local one.

When I call it like:

```
EXECUTE
'WITH rows_to_delete 
AS (DELETE from my_remote_server_public_foo 
    WHERE id_foo 
    IN 
    (SELECT * FROM my_remote_server_public_view_of_rows_to_delete) RETURNING *) 
INSERT INTO my_local_table 
SELECT * FROM rows_to_delete';
```

It lasts 5 min... Again becouse `DELETE` query have no access to indexes... Do I need to use `dblink` calling a function here too? Any other workaround?

Comment: Can you provide an example for what you want to do?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe question updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not that `postgres_fdw` “has no access to indexes”, it is that aggregate functions are not “pushed down” to the remote server.

There is no good way to do this yet, although aggregate push down is clearly on the list of things that PostgreSQL would like to add.

The best way is to use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) for requirements like that.

In PostgreSQL 9.6 there is a new feature in [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html) that you could abuse to push down a function.
You'd have to create an extension that contains the function and install it on both the local and the remote database. Then you can add this extension to the `extensions` property on the foreign server. If the function is `IMMUTABLE` and you call it locally, it will be pushed down to the remote server.
But that's ugly beyond description, and I would not recommend it.

The question raised as “update” has nothing to do with the problem and should have been raised as a separate question.

The problems here are that with PostgreSQL 9.5 or lower

- joins between foreign tables are not pushed down to the remote side
- updates and deletes operate row by row, necessitating a round trip per deleted row

Both have been improved with PostgreSQL 9.6 (not so the aggregates).